# Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x70745092)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

So as the title said, I'm getting this error in my code. There's no output besides the usual `(lldb)` thing. The line it's pointing to is

> 0x10df051:  movl   8(%edx), %edi0x10df051:  movl   8(%edx), %edi

The code itself is

```
DeltaViewController *deltaview = [[DeltaViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DeltaViewController" bundle:nil];
```

It happened when I selected an object in my picker and it should add a subview.

Comment: Have you run the Zombies instrument in Instruments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`deltaview` is DeltaViewController type, so it's a controller, not a view. After you've added it as a subview of self.view ([self.view addSubview:deltaview.view];), you might release the `deltaview`. Then whenever you sent a method (which is implemented in DeltaViewController) to `deltaview`, you'll get this EXC_BAD_ACCESS error of course.

A simple solution: Just declare `deltaview` (actually, it should be `deltaViewController` instead) as an iVar instead of local variable.

---

#### EDIT:

Well, here's a simple code snippet:

YourViewController.h:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController

@property DeltaViewController *deltaViewController;

@end
```

YourViewController.m:

```
@implementation YourViewController

@synthesize deltaViewController;
...

- (void)aMethod;

@end

- (void)dealloc {
  self.deltaViewController = nil; // set it to nil & release it after yourViewController dealloced.
  [super dealloc];
}

- (void)aMethod {
  DeltaViewController *deltaViewController = [[DeltaViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DeltaViewController" bundle:nil];
  // ...(setup deltaViewController)
  self.deltaViewController = deltaViewController; // it'll retain deltaViewController
  [deltaViewController release];

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't know how to do that. Sorry, I'm really beginner!

Comment: @NickScottman [HERE](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) is a doc on iVar. I think you'd better study on it first. :)

Comment: @NickScottman a simple code snippet is shown above, hope it'll help you.

Comment: Ok i put it in. what do i put in the `-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component` method?

Comment: @NickScottman what's that? If you've got a new problem, you need to create a new question on SO. :)

Comment: @NickScottman well, no one can offer more help if you don't describe your question clearly..

Comment: in the `-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component` method, what code do I put? what should happen when I select the row if it's defined in a different method?

Comment: @NickScottman a UITableView type of class? You can send you code to me via email. :)

Comment: ill send u the .xcodeproj file. send it back fixed or at least tell me what to do.